# Topological spaces are determined by their double?

Tags: general-topology

Is it true that if $X, Y$ are topological spaces and $X\sqcup X$ is homeomorphic to $Y\sqcup Y$ (giving these the disjoint union topology), then $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$?

It is easy to see that this holds for connected spaces but I'd like to know more generally.
If this is false, I'd also be interested in knowing if it works for say Hausdorff or metrizable spaces.

Comment: I'm not sure how well-received a link-only answer would be, but the question is answered in the negative (even for compact metric spaces) in "A Counterexample Related to Topological Sums" by Yamamoto and Yamashita, which can be found [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-12/S0002-9939-06-08596-0/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even for compact metric spaces, see the paper [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2006-134-12/S0002-9939-06-08596-0/S0002-9939-06-08596-0.pdf).

Hopefully this closes the question. (good find by @Thorgott)..